# How can I create cookies or sessions in android platform?

Tags: android

How can I create cookies or sessions in android platform?

I am using one application like preferences settings. when I change the theme of android application need to store somewhere(?) the last updated theme name.

Is there any way to store values cookies in android platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want them to be stored forever, until they're changed, it's `SharedPreferences` you're after.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myPreferenceDatabase", 0);
String mySetting = prefs.getString("savedPropertyName", "defaultValue");
```

For editing

```
Editor e = prefs.edit();
e.putString("savedPropertyName", "newValue");
e.commit();
```

If you just want the item to be stored until the application is closed, you should consider using a global static variable.

Comment: i'm glad to hear it. when you receive an answer that you find to be correct, please consider accepting it